# Finding 3rd point coordinates of rectangular triangle

Tags: triangles, coordinate-systems

I have to calculate coordinates of 3rd point of rotated image in programming language.

This are images, so coordinates are **always positive**, where left top corner is `0,0`

**In first scenario** I have coordinates of 2 points `A`,`B`, length `a` and `b` and always `90'` on point `A` .
I need to find coordinates of `C[Cx,Cy]` no matter which way triangle is rotated `PIC.1` & `PIC.2`.
[image]

**In second scenario** I have coordinates of `A`, `Alpha` angle, length `a` and `b`, always `90'` on `B` side. `PIC.3` Same thing - I need to know point C coordinates, no mater how I will rotate triangle.
[image]

**How I do it now.** I'm 'adding' two triangles and calculate them using angle & Pitagoras. This way I get `X1`,`X2`,`X3`,`X4` which I can sum/subtract.
Problem with this method is I have to determine triangle position - pattern is different depending on its position. See `PIC.4`.
[image]

I will be glad if you guys can provide me easy copy/paste formula to calculate `Cx` and `Cy` no matter which direction triangle is facing.

Comment: I think you should focus on how to rotate *all* points in such a situation.  Any rotation of the plane will have one point that remains fixed (the *center* of rotation), and an *angle* of rotation.  Once you have discovered the center and the angle of rotation, the formula you want is most easily expressed using matrix notation.  The matrix is $2\times 2$ for a plane rotation, so you would be able to "unwind" the matrix expression into lines of programming code pretty easily.

Comment: Image comes to me already rotated. I know the rotation because I'm finding markers. So yeah, I could rotate whole image first, but rotating image is 'consuming' task, making calculations are very fast. My current solution is working, but have some issues.
I also don't know what is unclear in my question. I just want to get `Cx` & `Cy` coordinates of `90'` triangle (see Pic.1).

Answer (score 2):

The point A has coordinates $(A_x, A_y)$ and point B has coordinates $(B_x, B_y)$ so the line through A and B is given by $y= \frac{B_y- A_y}{B_x- A_x}(x- A_x)+ A_y$.  The line through A perpendicular to that is given by $y= \frac{B_x- A_x}{A_y- B_y}(x- A_x)+ A_y$.  Also the circle with center $(A_x, A_y)$ with radius b is given by $(x- A_x)^2+ (y- A_y)^2= b^2$.  The point C, which lies on that perpendicular at distance d from A, lies on the intersection of that line and circle.  Solve the two equations $y= \frac{B_x- A_x}{A_y- B_y}(x- A_x)+ A_y$ and $(x- A_x)^2+ (y- A_y)^2= b^2$. An obvious start is to replace "y" in $(x- A_x)^2+ (y- A_y)^2= b^2$ with $y= \frac{B_x- A_x}{A_y- B_y}(x- A_x)+ A_y$ and then solve the single equation $(x- A_x)^2+ (\frac{B_x- A_x}{A_y- B_y}(x- A_x))^2= b$ for x.

There will be two solutions- one on either side of the line through A and B.

Comment: and what if I don't have point `B`? only Point `A`, `Alpha angle`, length of `a` and `b`?